# Custom UITableView cell with UIImage from border to border

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UIImage` that should be covering the entire cell. I created the size of the cell as 320x104 and the image as 320x104.

I set autolayout constraints on the `UIImage` for Leading,Trailing,Top and Bottom space to container.

However when I run my application, the image is not taking the full width of the cell, there is a white space before and after the cell.

---

Adding Image as requested, (The Orange color is in place of the image, the grey bars on the right and the left are the unwanted parts.)

[image]

Comment: before and after horizontally or vertically? include an image.

Comment: Please post an image.

Comment: don't set an image in the UIImageView.  Give it a bright, distinctive background color instead.  Then post an image of that here.

Comment: I uploaded image as requested

Comment: The bars also appear on all phone size 5S,6 and 6 Plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: add constraints]

Blue checkbox should be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Delete constraints from UIImageView to UITableViewCell and add them again using the "pin" menu from bottom without checking "constrain to margins" option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I marked the below answer as correct as it contains a visual description that might be helpful to future viewers of the post